# Pattern matching or isInstanceOf in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose I have the following class hierarchy:

```
trait A; class A1 extends A; class A2 extends A
```

Now I need to filter `A1` instances in `List[A]`. I use either pattern matching or `isInstanceOf`.

```
 as.filter(cond(_){case _: A1 => true}) // use pattern matching
 as.filter(_.isInstanceOf[A1]) // use isInstanceOf
```

Does it work the same ? What would you prefer ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you use collect? That has the added benefit that the returned list will be of the right type (List[A1] instead of List[A])

```
val a1s = as.collect { case x:A1 => x }
```

Comment: This also works for matching against Java types, not just Scala types (tested as of 2.11.4)

Answer (score 7):

While the accepted answer gives you a good advice, please note that typecase in scala is not different than using `isInstanceOf` combined with `asInstanceOf`. This two examples are roughly equivalent:

```
def foo(x: Any) = x match {
   case s: String = println(s"$s is a String)
   case _ => println("something else")
}

def foo(x: Any) = x match {
   case _ if x.isInstanceOf[String] => println(s${x.asInstanceOf[String]} is a String)
   case _ => println("something else")
}
```

So in your specific example it doesn't really matter which of the two you use: you'll always end up doing some kind of downcasting, which is something to generally avoid.

See how the second version is considerably uglier, hence more appropriate, since you're doing a "ugly" thing in a functional language.

So, I'd go with

```
val a1s = as.collect{case x if x.isInstanceOf[A1] => x.asInstanceOf[A1]}
```

Ugly things should look ugly.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it work the same?

The same answer will be generated, but different code will be emitted in each case, as you  might expect.

You can examine the IL which is generated in each case, as follows. Create a "`test.scala`" file with the following contents:

```
import PartialFunction.cond

trait A; class A1 extends A; class A2 extends A

class Filterer {
  def filter1(as: List[A]) =
    as.filter(cond(_){case _: A1 => true}) // use pattern matching

  def filter2(as: List[A]) =
    as.filter(_.isInstanceOf[A1]) // use isInstanceOf
}
```

Then run:

```
scalac test.scala
```

To examine the IL for the `as.filter(cond(_){case _: A1 => true})` version, do

```
javap -c 'Filterer$$anonfun$filter1$1'
javap -c 'Filterer$$anonfun$filter1$1$$anonfun$apply$1'
```

Then to examine the IL for the `as.filter(_.isInstanceOf[A1])` version, you can do

```
javap -c 'Filterer$$anonfun$filter2$1'
```

The "`cond`" version uses more intermediate values and instantiates more objects representing the extra anonymous functions involved.